# How to make a free fly camera script in unity with acceleration and decceleration?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, quaternions

I've written a camera free fly script that can so far look freely by rotating around the y and z axis in unity. The issue is I can't get it to accelerate relative to the direction its looking depending on the key pressed.

I've already tried using local transform constants like transform.forward. It doesn't work for some reason. I've also tried applying local direction vectors to acceleration and multiplying the acceleration vector by transform.rotation. I'm doing this for a game idea but also just for learning purposes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    //unity controls and constants input
    [SerializeField] public float accelerationMod;
    [SerializeField] public float xAxisSensitivity;
    [SerializeField] public float yAxisSensitivity;
    [SerializeField] public float deccelerationMod;
    [SerializeField] public string forwards;
    [SerializeField] public string backwards;
    [SerializeField] public string left;
    [SerializeField] public string right;
    [SerializeField] public string up;
    [SerializeField] public string down;

    private Vector3 moveSpeed;
    private bool xVector;
    private bool yVector;
    private bool zVector;

    void Start()
    {
        moveSpeed = new Vector3();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Debug.Log(moveSpeed);
        //was this axis moved on?
        xVector = false;
        yVector = false;
        zVector = false;
        //acceleration this iteration
        Vector3 acceleration = new Vector3();

        //mouse input
        float rotationHorizontal = xAxisSensitivity * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float rotationVertical = yAxisSensitivity * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        //applying mouse rotation
        transform.localEulerAngles = transform.localEulerAngles + new Vector3 (-rotationVertical, rotationHorizontal, 0);

        //key input detection
        if (Input.GetKey(forwards))
        {
            //Debug.Log(forwards);
            xVector = true;
            acceleration += transform.forward;
            Debug.Log(acceleration);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(left))
        {
            //Debug.Log(left);
            zVector = true;
            acceleration += -transform.right;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(backwards))
        {
            //Debug.Log(backwards);
            xVector = true;
            acceleration += -transform.forward;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(right))
        {
            //Debug.Log(right);
            zVector = true;
            acceleration += transform.right;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(up))
        {
            //Debug.Log(up);
            yVector = true;
            acceleration += transform.up;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(down))
        {
            //Debug.Log(down);
            yVector = true;
            acceleration += -transform.up;
        }

        //decceleration functionality
        if (!xVector)
        {
            //Debug.Log("xVector");
            if (Math.Abs(moveSpeed.x) < deccelerationMod)
            {
                moveSpeed = new Vector3(0, moveSpeed.y, moveSpeed.z);
            }
            else
            {
                moveSpeed = new Vector3(moveSpeed.x - deccelerationMod * Math.Sign(moveSpeed.x), moveSpeed.y, moveSpeed.z);
            }
        }

        if (!yVector)
        {
            //Debug.Log("yVector");
            if (Math.Abs(moveSpeed.y) < deccelerationMod)
            {
                moveSpeed = new Vector3(moveSpeed.x, 0, moveSpeed.z);
            }
            else
            {
                moveSpeed = new Vector3(moveSpeed.x, moveSpeed.y - deccelerationMod * Math.Sign(moveSpeed.y), moveSpeed.z);
            }
        }

        if (!zVector)
        {
            //Debug.Log("zVector");
            if (Math.Abs(moveSpeed.z) < deccelerationMod)
            {
                moveSpeed = new Vector3(moveSpeed.x, moveSpeed.y, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                moveSpeed = new Vector3(moveSpeed.x, moveSpeed.y, moveSpeed.z - deccelerationMod * Math.Sign(moveSpeed.z));
            }
        }


        Debug.Log(acceleration);
        //processing acceleration and applying it to movementSpeed/Velocity.
        acceleration = transform.TransformVector(acceleration);
        acceleration.Normalize();
        acceleration *= accelerationMod;
        moveSpeed += acceleration;
        Debug.Log(moveSpeed);
        //applying movementSpeed/Velocity
        transform.Translate(moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

I ultimately want a movement controller with 3 axis rotation controls, acceleration, and deceleration. If you are familiar with the game "Space Engineers", I'm trying to replicate their movement system. Currently the movement seems random but I suspect that it's because I'm applying rotations wrong or not translating to the right reference space.

Comment: Fyi from [`Transform.localEulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html): Only use this variable to read and set the angles to absolute values. Don't increment them, as it will fail when the angle exceeds 360 degrees. Use `Transform.Rotate` instead. To use `aceleration +=` will end up in an odd user experience because the movement will be like in space and you keep moving in the same direction even after rotating .. you shouldn't store that at all but rather move in forward direction and sidewards separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. By directly applying these you mgiht get a gimbal lock in your rotation. You should set the `Y` rotation in **global** coordinates and only the `X` rotation local space.
2. Then you confused `left` and `backwards` for the cases `Input.GetKey(left)` (should use the X-Axis) and `Input.GetKey(backwards)` (should use the Z-Axis).
3. Then later you used `TransformVector` on the acceleration which does

   > Transforms vector from local space to world space.

   However, [`transform.Translate(moveSpeed)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) by default moves in **local** space! Thus the `moveSpeed` and also `acceleration` should stay in local space.

I additionally refactored your code a bit:

- I would rather use `KeyCode` instead of `string` for the controlls so you only can select from the existing options which is less error prone

  [image]
- I personally would always also add a clamping for the vertical rotation so you don't end up upside-down

  [image]

  - you could/should also clamp the `moveSpeed` to a maximum magnitude to avoid a user to just accelerate into infinity and getting lost in space ;)

so the code could look like this

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Constants")]

    //unity controls and constants input
    public float AccelerationMod;
    public float XAxisSensitivity;
    public float YAxisSensitivity;
    public float DecelerationMod;

    [Space]

    [Range(0, 89)] public float MaxXAngle = 60f;

    [Space]

    public float MaximumMovementSpeed = 1f;

    [Header("Controls")]

    public KeyCode Forwards = KeyCode.W;
    public KeyCode Backwards = KeyCode.S;
    public KeyCode Left = KeyCode.A;
    public KeyCode Right = KeyCode.D;
    public KeyCode Up = KeyCode.Q;
    public KeyCode Down = KeyCode.E;

    private Vector3 _moveSpeed;


    private void Start()
    {
        _moveSpeed = Vector3.zero;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        HandleMouseRotation();

        var acceleration = HandleKeyInput();

        _moveSpeed += acceleration;

        HandleDeceleration(acceleration);

        // clamp the move speed
        if(_moveSpeed.magnitude > MaximumMovementSpeed)
        {
            _moveSpeed = _moveSpeed.normalized * MaximumMovementSpeed;
        }

        transform.Translate(_moveSpeed);
    }

    private Vector3 HandleKeyInput()
    {
        var acceleration = Vector3.zero;

        //key input detection
        if (Input.GetKey(Forwards))
        {
            acceleration.z += 1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(Backwards))
        {
            acceleration.z -= 1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(Left))
        {
            acceleration.x -= 1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(Right))
        {
            acceleration.x += 1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(Up))
        {
            acceleration.y += 1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(Down))
        {
            acceleration.y -= 1;
        }

        return acceleration.normalized * AccelerationMod;
    }

    private float _rotationX;

    private void HandleMouseRotation()
    {
        //mouse input
        var rotationHorizontal = XAxisSensitivity * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        var rotationVertical = YAxisSensitivity * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        //applying mouse rotation
        // always rotate Y in global world space to avoid gimbal lock
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationHorizontal, Space.World);

        var rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;

        _rotationX += rotationVertical;
        _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, -MaxXAngle, MaxXAngle);

        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-_rotationX, rotationY, 0);
    }

    private void HandleDeceleration(Vector3 acceleration)
    {
        //deceleration functionality
        if (Mathf.Approximately(Mathf.Abs(acceleration.x), 0))
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(_moveSpeed.x) < DecelerationMod)
            {
                _moveSpeed.x = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                _moveSpeed.x -= DecelerationMod * Mathf.Sign(_moveSpeed.x);
            }
        }

        if (Mathf.Approximately(Mathf.Abs(acceleration.y), 0))
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(_moveSpeed.y) < DecelerationMod)
            {
                _moveSpeed.y = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                _moveSpeed.y -= DecelerationMod * Mathf.Sign(_moveSpeed.y);
            }
        }

        if (Mathf.Approximately(Mathf.Abs(acceleration.z), 0))
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(_moveSpeed.z) < DecelerationMod)
            {
                _moveSpeed.z = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                _moveSpeed.z -= DecelerationMod * Mathf.Sign(_moveSpeed.z);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should give you the behavior you were looking for.

[Here is what it looks like (gif too big for adding here directly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0r5e.jpg)

---

Comment: Just tested your solution! Much more effective than mine. Thank you!